# Open settings URL from user notification?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

Opening settings URLs works for me from a UIAlertController but not from a UNUserNotificationCenter notification. Both approaches use the same URLs and the same code, namely this function:

```
  func open() {
    if let url = self.url {
      if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: { (success) in
          Log.log("Opened settings url: \(url), \(success)", true)
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

My logging line shows the completionHandler gets called with true from the alert and false from the notification. At first I thought it might be an issue with the phone being locked, but I also got false through a notification interacted with on the home screen.

What do I need to do to get this to work from notifications?

Comment: can you try it with `main` queue? and can you show your url?

Comment: @elia wrapping the open call with DispatchQueue.main.async gave me the same result, and I've tried this with multiple URLs, e.g. "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with ".foreground" in options while declaring UNNotificationAction.

(this action should cause the application to launch in the foreground.)